# How can I show wordpress posts based on author?

Tags: posts, author

I'm working on a site that will have 6 authors. Each author will have their own page that will only show their posts.

what is the best way to handle this?

I would like to do by creating a page or using the url such as /?a=username. However, if there is a more standard or a better way feel free to suggest that instead.

Thanks!

Comment: I've found I can use /?author_name=UserName. Is this the best way to handle this need?

Comment: If you set up your permalink structure, you can have it look cleaner but I'm not sure what you mean by best way. http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Answer (score 2):

Create an author.php page. It should take care of that. Check this page for more info http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates

Comment: ?author_name= worked great.

Comment: @dcp3450 : change your permalink structure to make your links search engine friendly.